# Get value from a Nested MongoDocs where conditions are met

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb

I have a bit strange mongoDB structure. Unfortunately I'm just a beginner in mongo, so cannot write the proper query to get the necessary value.

Here is the mongo example:

```
{"save1":
    {"date": "2019-05-05",
    "data":[
            {"data":{
                "base_id":1,
                "name": "name_1",
                "rarity" : 7,
                "gear": 12}
                },
            {"data":{
                "base_id":2,
                "name": "name_3",
                "rarity" : 5,
                "gear": 8}
                },
            {"data":{
                "base_id":3,
                "name": "name_3",
                "rarity" : 2,
                "gear": 10}
                },
            {"data":{
                "base_id":4,
                "name": "name_4",
                "rarity" : 3,
                "gear": 2}
                }
            ]}

}
```

I need the "rarity" and "gear" WHERE the base_id is 3 like this

{"rarity": 2, "gear": 10}

I guess it is possible with projection, but because I have an array in save1.data don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
db.test.aggregate({$project: {"data": "$save1.data"}}, {$unwind: "$data"}, {$match: {"data.data.base_id": 3}})
```

Comment: I have used this code base on your suggestion
```py
import pymongo

dbclient = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017')
mydb = dbclient['mydatabase']
col_discord = mydb['test']

value = col_discord.aggregate({'$project': {"data": "$save1.data"}}, {'$unwind': "$data"}, {'$match': {"data.data.base_id": 3}})
```

it is drop  "TypeError: aggregate() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given"

Comment: Try enclosing the aggregation in an array

`col_discord.aggregate([{'$project': {"data": "$save1.data"}}, {'$unwind': "$data"}, {'$match': {"data.data.base_id": 3}]}`

Comment: almost there ;)
I need a for cycle to get the values

for i in value:
    print (i['data']['data'])

but it gives me the required data. THX

Comment: Also, please close this question by upvoting and marking the answer as accepted if this answer has helped you.